# Purpose of RemoveAll()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to Linq. From my understanding LINQ should be used only to query but not for modification of a collection or db etc.

If that is the case why did Microsoft provide `RemoveAll()` extension?

As far as my understanding goes `RemoveAll()` modifies the collection.

Is it not against the purpose of Linq?

Can some please explain the reason for providing `RemoveAll()`?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect.

Comment: John, I disagree. A core concept of LINQ is to provide functional programming aspects such as immutability (and of course deferred execution). RemoveAll does violate that. For example, a common argument as to why there is no built in Enumerable.ForEach extension method is that it violates the principal of immutability. HOWEVER, to the OPs question (and as noted by SLaks), RemoveAll is NOT LINQ and is not an extension method at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`RemoveAll()` is part of the `List<T>` class from .Net 2.0.
It has nothing to do with LINQ; it predates LINQ by a couple of years.

`List<T>` has a number of methods that do the same thing as LINQ methods, including `ConvertAll`, `Exists`, `Find`, `FindAll`, `FindLast`, and `TrueForAll`.

It also has the `ForEach` method, which [is not LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: And dont forget about List's Reverse().... Not quite the same as LINQ's Reverse()..

Comment: @jdv: Or `Sort()`; that why I didn't mention them.